# androvm not starting in virtualbox

Tags: android, init, androvm

I have windows xp 32 bit. 
I have installed sun virtual box 4.3.6 . 
I downloaded the androvm version 4.1.1 and imported it in the virtualbox. It got imported nicely.

When i start the androvm virtul machine - the boot window opens, but after some time it says

```
  inti: untacked pid 272(number varies) exited
```

I also used androvmplayer. I have run from it also. but the same error keeps coming

i searched. i gone through the log of the virtualbox but nothing much i can see.

can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial on AndroVM.org: [AndroVM – Configuration Tutorial](http://androvm.org/blog/blog/2012/11/14/androvm-configuration-tutorial/)

Make sure you configured the Host-only adapter correctly as described and you launched the AndroVMPlayer (get it from the Download page).